# Using Zurb Foundation with Dreamweaver

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, dreamweaver

I am trying to use Zurb Foundation with Adobe Dreamweaver 2014.

I have created a site from a directory which has the foundation files in.  But when I view the page in the editor is is completely wrong.  Where as when I open the page in any browser it look fine.

Is there any extra config I need to do to to get this so I can edit the pages correctly.

All the fonts look large and not the design doesn't look like it should.

The upshot is that I currently use a text editor to design my pages and I'd like to get Dreamweaver on the go.

Cheers,

Comment: you can apply styling to a project and document at design time : https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/css-styles-panel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the way that Dreamweaver's interface renders it using whatever engine they're using. Just be sure to launch any changes you've made into a real browser, like Google Chrome, before uploading your files to a live server. I have the same issue sometimes. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input +1, although hasn't answered my question.  Appreciated anyway, thanks.  Unfortunately Dreamweaver is totally unusable.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you more insight. I'm giving your post a +1 as well because I'd like to know why this happens as well. Not hindering my development projects but, I just want to know "WHY?!". Haha.

Comment: I also found this. Give it a try? 
As a work around, you can edit your un-styled page by disabling CSS.....View -> Style Rendering -> un-tick "Display Styles"

Comment: Thanks, that's a little better.  I have just found Live View, which displays it correctly.  It's a lot better than the design view and you can have split mode too.

Comment: You didn't have Live View on?? lol...i was under the impression that you did...it renders it WAY better but still has some bugs...glad i could help...good luck to you

Comment: Haha, first time I have seen it, oh well I'll know for next time.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool to help setup and manage a foundation website is Codekit. http://incident57.com/codekit/

It has a feature that sets up a foundation website for you. Open it up in Dreamweaver and take it from there.